# How to Upgrade Redis Database from 5.x to 6.x

Tags: redis

This instance was running Redis version 5.0.8 open source. The Redis packages have been updated to the current 6.0.3 and now the server reports `Loading RDB produced by version 5.0.8` on startup. What is the proper method for upgrading the RDB to the version of the server? I have checked the [admin documentation](https://redis.io/topics/admin) and there's nothing mentioned. Also, I checked the [6.0 release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/6.0/00-RELEASENOTES) and nothing there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade is automatic on first run of Redis after upgrading the packages. Subsequent times that Redis starts it reports `Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.3`.